# Java objects escaping window frame

Tags: java

So I made a game and I want the enemies to bounce off the wall when they hit in a random x and y speed. However, somehow these little buggers are still getting out of the window. Most the time it works but every like 10ish times it will sneak out the border and I can't figure out how.

```
@Override
    public void tick()
    {
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
        Random r = new Random();

        //BUGS
        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) //This is correct size of the window edges
        {
            if(speedY <= 0)
                speedY = (r.nextInt(8) + 1);
            else
                speedY = -(r.nextInt(8) + 1);
        }
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 32) //This is correct size of the window edges
        {
            if(speedX <= 0)
                speedX = (r.nextInt(8) + 1);
            else
                speedX = -(r.nextInt(8) + 1);
        }
```

Comment: I would imagin that if a bug is "too far" of the screen, then it cannot "return" in one tick and just keeps switchting directions. A possibility to fix the problem is to only switch directions if a bug is over the negative-y boundary with negative-y speed or over the positive-y boundary with positive-y speed,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

- Don't re-create Random as it's wasteful and sometimes dangerous. Better to create one Random object and assign it to an instance field of the class, and use it throughout.
- Avoid "magic numbers". So instead of `y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48`, do `y >= Game.HEIGHT - WINDOW_EDGES` (or something similar)
- Don't swap speed as you're doing but instead check for `y <= 0` or `y >= Game.HEIGHT -SOME_CONSTANT` separately, and gear the results based on this finding to avoid getting caught in a speed "trap".  This is your main problem in fact.

e.g.,

```
if (y <= 0) {
    speedY = r.nextInt(8) + 1; // change 8 to a constant
} else if (y >= Game.HEIGHT - SOME_CONSTANT) {
    speedY = -(r.nextInt(8) + 1);
}
```

Same for x and speedX

Regarding:

> 2) I would like to do that but since I have multiple object sizes, I have to change the edges.

Then each object should have a method that returns its edge size (or whatever property is needed), and you should use this, again, not magic numbers

> 3) I tried swapping and they just shot off the screen.

I don't know what you mean by this or what specific code changes you may have made.

If still stuck, consider creating and posting a valid [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Okay couple things. 1) It was my only method in the class so I just put it there, but I moved to top of class in case later I add more so thanks. 2) I would like to do that but since I have multiple object sizes, I have to change the edges. 3) I tried swapping and they just shot off the screen.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Last question, what is the speed "trap" you are referring to? Sorry I am new programmer as you can probably tell

Comment: @AndrewWilken: your code swaps directions but does so without regard for which bound is being struck. If the sprite strikes a bound in such a way that the direction code is called more than once, it will swap directions back and forth.